# Scala: Shorthand for pattern match on type?

Tags: scala

Is there a more elegant way of doing the following?

```
data match {
  case e: SomeType => doSomethingWith(e)
  case _ =>
}
```

Looking for something like:

```
data.ifInstanceOf[SomeType](doSomethingWith)
```

Comment: Ugh, this should be harder, not easier.

Comment: It's quite possible there's a better way that uses polymorphism. On the other hand, in this case the SomeType is a mixin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, this didn't come up:

```
import PartialFunction._

condOpt("abc": Any) { case s: String => s.length } // = Some(3)
condOpt((): Any) { case s: String => s.length } // = None
```

I usually rename it or its sibling `cond` to `when`.

Comment: The edit reviewer who said REPL format is better was right. You can cut/paste the transcript directly to a REPL. However, you can't save the session (which would give you just the LOC). https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9214

Answer (score 4):

Do you want an expression or just perform a side-effect? If just a side-effect via "PimpMyLibrary" approach + refection:

```
  import scala.reflect.ClassTag

  implicit class AnyOps(data : Any) {
     def ifInstanceOf[A : ClassTag](f: A => Unit) : Unit = {
        val clzz = implicitly[ClassTag[A]].runtimeClass
        if (clzz.isInstance(data)) f(data.asInstanceOf[A])      
     }
  }
```

You can then try

```
"abc".ifInstanceOf[String](println)
"def".ifInstanceOf[Integer](println)
1.ifInstanceOf[Integer](println)
2.ifInstanceOf[String](println)
```

If you want an expression I think the best way to go is to add an additional type Parameter B and return Either[B, Anyref].

Comment: Pattern matcher will use your ClassTag: `implicit class AnyOps(data: Any) { def as[A: ClassTag](f: A=>Any) = data match { case a: A => f(a) case _ => } }`

Answer (score 4):

I think a `collect` might work for this.  The method takes a partial function, and filters out elements that did not match any `case` statements:

```
Option(data) collect {
    case element: SomeType => mappingFunction(element)
}
```

Of course, `mappingFunction` here could have side effects and return `Unit`, thereby mimicking a `foreach`.

If you want to make a new named method, you could make a new method on `Any`:

```
implicit class AnyOps(data: Any) {
    def forMatch[A](pf: PartialFunction[Any, A]) = pf.lift(data)
}
```

Comment: How will a collect work? `data` can be any class which need not have a collect method defined on it.

Comment: @mohit sorry I forgot to wrap `data` in `Option` so that you have a `collect` method.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asInstanceOf` to get your goal:

```
Option(data)
  .filter(_.isInstanceOf[SomeType])
  .map(_.asInstanceOf[SomeType])
  .map(doSomethingWith)
```

but I guess it's too verbose.

Comment: The goal is to apply a function if the type matches `T`, not to cast to `T` and then apply.

Comment: @Marth Your solution is scala idiomatic way. Don't try find better

Comment: I wasn't the one who asked the question, and I do agree that is original proposition is the best way to do what he wants. I'm just pointing at that your solution is semantically different from his : yours will apply `doSomethingWith` whether or not `data` is `SomeType`, whereas his will not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find it difficult to find anything shorter or more precise than "good old"...

```
if (data.isInstanceOf[SomeType]) doSomething(data)
```

... unless your case is more complicated than you're showing

Comment: In the above example, wouldn't the doSomething(data) need to be doSomething(data.asInstanceOf[SomeType])?

Comment: You're absolutely right; that will diminish the usefulness when you need that type as input; which is likely.